# Why does Hibernate Envers not respect the column type in the original table?

Tags: hibernate-envers

I am using **Hibernate 5.2.9.Final** (version of both the core & Envers). When added auditing to a table, created with:

```
CREATE TABLE Transaction (
    id                      BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
   ,name                    VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL
   ,currency                CHAR(3) REFERENCES Currency(code)
   ,country                 VARCHAR(3)
   ,status                  INTEGER
   ,description             VARCHAR(1000)
   ,amount                  NUMERIC(30,5)
   ,closingDate             TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
   ,rangeStart              TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
   ,rangeEnd                TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
   ,isin                    VARCHAR(12)
   ,version                 INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Hibernate Envers created the `_AUD` table, it spit out the following:

```
CREATE TABLE transaction_aud (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    rev integer NOT NULL,
    revtype smallint,
    closingdate timestamp without time zone,
    closingdate_mod boolean,
    country character varying(255),
    country_mod boolean,
    currency character varying(255),
    currency_mod boolean,
    description character varying(255),
    description_mod boolean,
    amount numeric(19,2),
    isin character varying(255),
    isin_mod boolean,
    name character varying(255),
    name_mod boolean,
    rangeend timestamp without time zone,
    rangeend_mod boolean,
    rangestart timestamp without time zone,
    rangestart_mod boolean,
    status integer,
    status_mod boolean
);
```

The entity mapping file is:

```
<entity name="Transaction" class="com.project.datamodel.TransactionTO" access="FIELD">
    <attributes>
        <id name="id" access="PROPERTY">
            <generated-value strategy="SEQUENCE" generator="TransactionIdSeq" />
            <sequence-generator name="TransactionIdSeq" sequence-name="TransactionIdSeq" allocation-size="1" />
        </id>
        <basic name="name" optional="false"> <column length="120" /> </basic>
        <basic name="currency"> <column columnDefinition="CHAR(3)" /> </basic>
        <basic name="country"> <column length="3" /> </basic>
        <basic name="status" />
        <basic name="description"> <column length="1000" /> </basic>
        <basic name="amount"> <column columnDefinition="NUMERIC(30,5)" /> </basic>
        <basic name="closingDate"> <column columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE" /> </basic>
        <basic name="rangeStart"> <column columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE" /> </basic>
        <basic name="rangeEnd"> <column columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE" /> </basic>
        <basic name="isin"> <column length="12" /> </basic>
        <transient name="favorite" />
        <version name="version" />
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

**NOTE:** I have removed all the joined `many-to-one` relations from the entity as they just add bulk without contributing to my main question.

The problems are:

### `VARCHAR`/`CHAR` fields type & length ignored

ALL `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` fields, regardless of their length were converted to `VARCHAR(255)`/`character varying(255)` fields.

This caused a problem when saving data in the `description` field that should normally hold 1000 characters. After the 255 limit size was exceeded, the database engine through an exception because the data was too wide for the column size.

Also, what sense does it make to cast a `CHAR(3)` to a `VARCHAR(255)`? It seems awfully wasteful to me, but I'm hoping that there is some other reason I am not aware of.

### `TIMESTAMP` time zone attribute ignored

The `TIMESTAMP`-typed fields changed from being explicitly defined **WITH** a time zone defined to not having the timezone defined (I'm aware that the `TIMESTAMP` type in PostgreSQL -which is my backing database engine- defined them without the time zone by default).

### Numeric precision type changed

The amount field defined as a `NUMERIC (30,5)` was defined in the audit table as `NUMERIC(19,2)`.

Why does Hibernate Envers not respect the column types of the original table when generating the `_AUD` table?

### Exceptional case

I have also found that it respects the size in the case of one table: `LocalizedMessage`

```
<entity name="LocalizedMessage" class="com.project.datamodel.to.LocalizedMessageTO" access="FIELD">
        <attributes>
                <id name="id" access="PROPERTY">
                        <generated-value strategy="SEQUENCE" generator="LocalizedMessageIdSeq" />
                        <sequence-generator name="LocalizedMessageIdSeq" sequence-name="LocalizedMessageIdSeq" allocation-size="1" />
                </id>
                <many-to-one name="adminMessage"> <join-column name="adminMessageId" /> </many-to-one>
                <basic name="localeCode"> <column length="7" /> </basic>
                <basic name="message"> <column length="500" /> </basic>
                <version name="version" />
        </attributes>
</entity>
```

The original table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE LocalizedMessage (
    id             BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
   ,adminMessageId BIGINT REFERENCES AdminMessage(id)
   ,localeCode     VARCHAR(7)
   ,message        VARCHAR(500)
   ,version        INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

And the generated `_AUD` table was:

```
CREATE TABLE localizedmessage_aud (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    rev integer NOT NULL,
    revtype smallint,
    localecode character varying(7),
    localecode_mod boolean,
    message character varying(500),
    message_mod boolean,
    adminmessageid bigint,
    adminmessage_mod boolean
);
```

## Envers mapping file definitions

*NOTE:* This was done AFTER adding the length directives to the mapping file. The only problematic fields now are the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and the `NUMERIC` fields (where the precision is changed), along with the `CHAR()` fields.
In essence, the `columnDefinition` attribute of the JPA XML mapping file is not respected.

Enabling trace logging for `org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl` produced log entries like the following:

```xml
2017-06-10 15:52:19,981 TRACE org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl ~ ------------------------------------------------------------
2017-06-10 15:52:19,984 TRACE org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl ~ Envers-generate entity mapping -----------------------------
<hibernate-mapping auto-import="false">
 <class entity-name="com.project.datamodel.to.TransactionTO_AUD" discriminator-value="Transaction" table="Transaction_AUD" schema="app" abstract="false">
  <composite-id name="originalId">
   <key-property name="id" type="long">
    <column name="id" length="255" scale="2" precision="19"/>
   </key-property>
   <key-many-to-one type="integer" class="com.project.datamodel.to.CustomRevisionEntity" name="REV">
    <column name="REV"/>
   </key-many-to-one>
  </composite-id>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="REVTYPE" type="org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.RevisionTypeType"/>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="closingDate" type="timestamp">
   <column name="closingDate" length="255" scale="2" precision="19"/>
  </property>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="closingDate_MOD" type="boolean"/>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="country" type="string">
   <column name="country" length="3" scale="2" precision="19"/>
  </property>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="country_MOD" type="boolean"/>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="currency" type="string">
   <column name="currency" length="255" scale="2" precision="19"/>
  </property>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="currency_MOD" type="boolean"/>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="description" type="string">
   <column name="description" length="1000" scale="2" precision="19"/>
  </property>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="description_MOD" type="boolean"/>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="amount" type="big_decimal">
   <column name="amount" length="255" scale="2" precision="19"/>
  </property>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="amount_MOD" type="boolean"/>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="isin" type="string">
   <column name="isin" length="12" scale="2" precision="19"/>
  </property>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="isin_MOD" type="boolean"/>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="name" type="string">
   <column name="name" length="120" scale="2" precision="19"/>
  </property>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="name_MOD" type="boolean"/>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="rangeEnd" type="timestamp">
   <column name="rangeEnd" length="255" scale="2" precision="19"/>
  </property>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="rangeEnd_MOD" type="boolean"/>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="rangeStart" type="timestamp">
   <column name="rangeStart" length="255" scale="2" precision="19"/>
  </property>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="rangeStart_MOD" type="boolean"/>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="status" type="converted::com.project.datamodel.converter.StatusConverter">
   <column name="status" length="255" scale="2" precision="19"/>
  </property>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="status_MOD" type="boolean"/>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And for the LocalizedMessage table:

```xml
2017-06-10 15:52:19,947 TRACE org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl ~ ------------------------------------------------------------
2017-06-10 15:52:19,949 TRACE org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl ~ Envers-generate entity mapping -----------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<hibernate-mapping auto-import="false">
 <class entity-name="com.project.datamodel.to.LocalizedMessageTO_AUD" discriminator-value="LocalizedMessage" table="LocalizedMessage_AUD" schema="app" abstract="false">
  <composite-id name="originalId">
   <key-property name="id" type="long">
    <column name="id" length="255" scale="2" precision="19"/>
   </key-property>
   <key-many-to-one type="integer" class="com.project.datamodel.to.CustomRevisionEntity" name="REV">
    <column name="REV"/>
   </key-many-to-one>
  </composite-id>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="REVTYPE" type="org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.RevisionTypeType"/>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="localeCode" type="string">
   <column name="localeCode" length="7" scale="2" precision="19"/>
  </property>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="localeCode_MOD" type="boolean"/>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="message" type="string">
   <column name="message" length="500" scale="2" precision="19"/>
  </property>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="message_MOD" type="boolean"/>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="adminMessage_id" type="long">
   <column name="adminMessageId" length="255" scale="2" precision="19"/>
  </property>
  <property insert="true" update="false" name="adminMessage_MOD" type="boolean"/>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Why does it apply correctly in one case and not in another?

Comment: Could you provide your entity mappings for the transaction entity?  Could you also specify what version of Hibernate & Hibernate Envers you're using?

Comment: @Naros Thank you! I have added the XML mapping file... I created the original table manually in SQL. You got me thinking that maybe I should have added all those sizes in the XML mapping file as well? (for Envers to pick them up from there) Is it not able to query the table structure in the DB?

Comment: Envers bases its mappings entirely on the data made available from Hibernate's mapping model, so no it doesn't look at the database schema directly.  Since your XML mapping does not specify any column lengths, the JPA default of 255 is used for strings for example.  If you specify the column lengths in your XML mapping file, Envers should adjust automatically.

Comment: @Naros I have added the sizes/column definitions to the mapping file and the columns in the audit table are still being generated incorrectly! Is there something I'm missing somewhere else?

Comment: Which Postgres dialect are you using?  I'm curious if you allow Hibernate and Envers to create their tables if you'd observe the same varying character data type being used across all tables and the difference is a product of manual vs automated creation with the dialect you're using.  One thing you can do is to enable trace logging for `org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl` to see the XML Envers generates for each entity mapping.  What you'll see is Envers is generates `type="string"` and its merely Hibernate and the dialect choice selecting character varying.

Comment: @Naros The log file says `HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`. I do not allow Hibernate to create the tables because the database schema is managed by Flyway (which supports clustering, whereas I believe Envers does not). I have added the log entries to the question. Essentially, the lengths are all respected now, only the `columnDefinition` attribute is being ignored. Perhaps I should specify the precisions/types in another way?

Comment: Updated my answer with why your column definitions aren't being reflected in the XML output.  TL;DR: Invalid XML :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in my comment, Envers does not interpret its schema from the existing database schema in any way.  In fact, its entire mapping model production process is based on inspecting Hibernate ORM's boot-time mapping model, which you can find in `org.hibernate.mapping`.

This means that for things such as column lengths, they should be supplied as part of your mapping model via either annotations or in your XML mapping file in order for Envers to generate properties that use those same lengths or in some cases custom column definitions.

If you specify the lengths in your XML mapping file and regenerate the Envers schema, it should align itself very closely with your Hibernate entity schema.

**UPDATE**

The reason you don't see the column definitions being rendered in the Envers mappings is because your JPA ORM.XML file is invalid, it isn't following the schema definition and thus not only would Envers not be seeing your column definitions, neither would Hibernate.

Your mappings should be:

```
<column column-definition="TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE"/>
```

You'll notice the attribute is named `column-definition` and not `columnDefinition`.